# Class fields versus preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

Philosophically, is it better to work with preferences throughout some code, getting and setting the values as the user interacts with the activity; or is it better to work with class fields, then later in some onDestroy() perhaps, set the preferences to the final values of the class fields than one wants to save.

```
//-- Is this better?
if (a==preferences.getInt(pref1,default){
   preferenceEditor.putInt(pref2,someNumber);
}

//-- Or is this?
if (a==field1){
  field2 = someNumber;
}
...
onDestroy(){
   preferenceEditor.putInt(pref1,field1);
   preferenceEditor.putInt(pref2,field2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, please don't "work with preferences".

What you're doing there (in your first sample) is interaction with a global variable. Never do this if you can help it. It's an anti-pattern. You don't want globals in your code. It makes the code harder to understand / harder to test. Instead, whenever you instantiate a class, read your global settings and add them to your class' fields (preferably in the constructor). The class itself must NOT know about your preferences storage.

Also, DO NOT USE onDestroy (WTF?). Here's a note from [the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29):

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!

Instead, place that logic in onPause().

Comment: thanks Alexandru!  And thanks for the reminder on onDestroy().

Answer (score 0):

for performance reasons fields should be preferred over preferences, but it also depends on how often the values change